# Setting jenkins pipeline variable using powershell results in carriage return

Tags: powershell, jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Jenkins Pipeline file for a standalone pipeline job, I am trying to find the latest folder created within a directory and assign this to a variable.

This works perfectly, except for the fact there is a rogue carriage return in the output. I can't use `Write-Host -NoNewLine` as this will not make it's way out as a parameter.

I have tried to replace any carriage returns on the file name, I have iterated over the ascii characters - it just seems that for some strange reason, Powershell always has this rogue "carriage return" that isn't when using `Write-Output`.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'orchestration'
  }
  environment {
    CLIENT_NAME = 'Test Client'
    LATEST_ORCHESTRATION_VERSION = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
        Write-Output (gci D:\\Orchestration | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime)[-1].Name
    ''')
  }
  stages {
      stage('Load') {
      steps {
         bat('dotnet run "D:\Orchestration\%LATEST_ORCHESTRATION_VERSION%" -d %WORKSPACE% -c %CLIENT_NAME%')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running this in Powershell works fine, but running if you do `Write-Output 'foo'` in Powershell ISE seems to replicate the carriage return (if I run the above powershell script purely in powershell it returns fine as far as I can see!)

When I run the pipeline, the environment variable pulls through perfectly but because the carriage return seems to exist, then I get the following error in my jenkins console:

````
D:\workspace\Test Client>dotnet run "D:\Orchestration\1.0.0.28

Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in D:\workspace\Test Client, or pass the path to the project using --project.```
````

Comment: It is very normal for a command-line program to return a newline at the end of its output. I'm not sure if you can suppress this in PowerShell, but, even if you can, I suspect it's a bug in the Jenkins powershell plugin you're using. Do you have the same problem if you run a powershell command via `bat` (`VERSION = bat('powershell -Command {Write-Output ...}'`)?

Comment: @jpaugh Good idea! I just tried this, in command prompt it returned but it doesn't write to the output and thus environment variable doesn't get set :(

Comment: I got strange results when trying to `Write-Output` also. The following worked from within cmd.exe: `powershell -Command "Write-Output 3"`.

Comment: Try to use `trim()` on the return of the `powershell` step, i.e. `LATEST_ORCHESTRATION_VERSION = powershell([...]).trim()`

Comment: @DominikGebhart thanks I will try this tomorrow!